# How to pass dynamic id from ajax data to Modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have dynamic ID which I am getting with an ajax POST request. Now I want to pass my dynamic id to a bootstrap modal. Is it possible?

```
var id = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{ url('/pos/createSubCategory') }}",
    data: {id: id},
    success: function (data) {

    var html = '';

    if(!$.trim(data))
    {
        html = '<div>' + '<h3>' + 'Empty!' + '</h3>' +'</div>';
    }
    else
    {
         $.each(data, function () {            
         html += '<div class="card subCategoryClass" data-target="#subcategory_product_modal" data-toggle="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" data-id="@this.id">' + '<p>' + '<button>' + this.name + '</button>' + '</p>' +'</div>';

         });
     }


    },
    error: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
});
```

> data-id="@this.id" not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the solution below:

Since it is variable you need to parse it by using + operator.

```js
var data = [{id: "1",name :"rishab"},{id: "2",name :"Ram"}]

var html = "";
$.each(data, function () {            
     html += '<div class="card subCategoryClass" data-target="#subcategory_product_modal" data-toggle="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" data-id="'+this.id+'">' + '<p>' + '<button>' + this.name + '</button>' + '</p>' +'</div>';

     });
         
         
console.log(html);
$("#op").append(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="op"></div>
```